# What do more than or less than sign with a line through them mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation

[image]

What do these symbols where the arrow point to mean? Does it mean `not less then`? If that's the case, why do we write it that way and not `>` if they are the same?

Comment: $a\not< b$ means $a\ge b$ but emphasizes the negation

Comment: @J.W.Tanner. That's not necessary the case if one's working with a partial ordering. For such one can have $a \not< b,$ $a \not> b,$ and $a \not= b$ at the same time.

Comment: @md2perpe:  that could be, but here it looks like OP is working with the usual order on the real numbers (or a subset of them)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$0\not<1$ means ‘$0$ is not less than $1$’, just as $a\ne b$ means ‘$a$ is not equal to $b$’. This is not the same as $0>1$; it **is** the same as $0\ge 1$, but in this case I suspect that $p$ is $0<1$, and the writer preferred to write the negated relation in a way that made the connection with $\sim p$ (‘not $p$’) obvious

Answer (score 1):

Pretty much for any logical symbol in mathematics, a diagonal line through it means the logical negation. Examples $\notin$, $\neq$, $\nexists$, etc.